# how to read a large log file which other process current write

Tags: java, file, io

Create log file by day， one file about 400MB，JVM memory about 2GB。
Have one process write a large log file with 'a' mode。
I want to read this file and be able to achieve some functions：

1. Append read newly written data
2. I will store the offset to restore the read after jvm restart

This is my simple implementation, but I don't know if the time and memory consumption are good. I want to know if there is a better way to solve this problem

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "D://test.log";
    long restoreOffset = resotoreOffset();
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
    randomAccessFile.seek(restoreOffset);
    while (true) {
        String line = randomAccessFile.readLine();
        if(line != null) {

            // doSomething(line);

            restoreOffset = randomAccessFile.getFilePointer();

            //storeOffset(restoreOffset);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not, unfortunately.

There are 2 major problems with this code. First I'll tackle the simple one, but the most important one is the second point.

### Encoding issues

> `String line = randomAccessFile.readLine();`

This line converts bytes to characters implicitly, and that's generally a bad idea, because bytes aren't characters, and converting from one to the other requires a charset encoding.

This method (`readLine()` from RAF) is a bizarre case - probably because RandomAccessFile is incredibly old API. Using this method will apply some bizarro ISO-8859-1 esque charset encoding: It converts bytes to chars by taking each byte as a complete char, assuming the byte represents the unicode character as listed, which isn't actually a sane encoding, just a lazy programmer.

The upshot for you is: Unless you can **guarantee** that this log file shall always only ever contain ASCII characters, this code is broken, and `readLine` cannot be used at all. Instead you'll have to do considerably more work: read bytes until you hit a newline, then turn the bytes so gathered into a string with  `new String(byteArray, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, or use `ByteBuffer` and apply similar tactics. But keep reading, because solving the second problem kinda solves this one automatically.

### Buffering

Modern computer systems tend to like 'packeting'. You can't really operate on a single byte. Take SSDs (though this applies to spinning platter disks as well): The actual SSD hardware can't read single bytes. It can only read entire blocks worth of data.

When you therefore ask the OS explicitly for a single byte, that ends up setting off a chain of events that causes the SSD to read the entire block, then pass that entire block to the operating system, which will then disregard everything except the one byte you wanted, and returns just that.

If your code then asks for the next byte, we do that routine again.

So, if you read 1024 bytes consecutively from an SSD that has 1024-byte blocks, doing so by calling `read()` 1024 times causes the SSD to perform 1024 reads, whereas calling `read(byteArr)` once, passing it a 1024-byte array, causes the SSD to perform a single read.

Yup, that means the byte array solution is literally 1000 times faster.

The same applies to networking, too. Sending 1 byte a thousand times is usually nearly 1000 times slower than sending 1000 bytes once; TCP/IP packets can carry about 1800 bytes worth of data, so sending any less than that gains you almost nothing.

RAF's `readLine()` works like the first (bad) scenario: It reads bytes one at a time until it hits a newline character. Thus, to read a 100 character string, it's 100x slower than just knowing you need to read 100 characters and reading them in one go.

### The solution

You may want to abandon RandomAccessFile entirely, it's quite old API.

A major issue with buffering is that it's a lot harder unless you know how many bytes to read beforehand. Here, you don't know that: You want to keep reading until you hit a newline character, but you have no idea how long it'll be until we get there. Furthermore, buffering APIs tend to just return what's convenient, and may therefore read fewer bytes than we ask for (it'll always read at least 1, though, unless we hit end of file). So, we need to write code that will repeatedly read entire chunk's worth of data, analyse the chunk for a newline, and if it's not there, keep reading.

Furthermore, opening channels and such is expensive. So, if you want to dig through all log lines, writing code that opens a new channel every time is suboptimal.

How about this, using the newer file API from `java.nio.file`:

```
public class LogLineReader implements AutoCloseable {
  private final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  private final ByteBuffer bb = wrap(buffer);
  private final SeekableByteChannel channel;
  private final Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

  public LogLineReader(Path p) {
    channel = Files.newByteChannel(p, StandardOpenOption.READ);
    channel.position(111L); // you seek to pos 111 in your code...
  }

  @Override public void close() throws IOException {
    channel.close();
  }

  // This code buffers: First, our internal buffer is scanned
  // for a new line. If there is no full line in the buffer,
  // we read bytes from the file and check again until we find one.

  public String readLine() {
    int len = 0;
    if (!channel.isOpen()) return null;

    int scanStart = 0;

    while (true) {
      // Scan through the bytes we have buffered for a newline.

      for (int i = scanStart; i < buffer.position(); i++) {
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
          // Found it. Take all bytes up to the new line, turn into
          // a string.
          String res = new String(buffer, 0, i, charset);

          // Copy all bytes from _after_ the newline to the front.
          System.arraycopy(buffer, i + 1, buffer, 0, buffer.position() - i - 1);

          // Adjust the position (which represents how many bytes are buffered).
          buffer.position(buffer.position() - i - 1);
          return res;
        }
      }
      scanStart = buffer.position();

      // If we get here, the buffer is empty or contains no newline.

      if (scanStart == buffer.limit()) {
        throw new IOException("Log line too long");
      }

      int read = channel.read(buffer); // let's fetch more bytes!

      if (read == -1) {
        // we've reached the end of the file.

        if (buffer.position() == 0) return null;
        return new String(buffer, 0, buffer.position(), charset);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the sake of efficiency, this code cannot deal with log lines longer than 1024 in length; feel free to up that number. If you want to be capable of reading infinite size loglines, at some point a gigantic buffer is a problem. If you must, you could write code that resizes the buffer if you hit 1024, or you can update this code that it'll keep reading, but only returns a truncated string with the first 1024 characters. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

NB: I also didn't test this, but at the very least it should give you the general gist of using SeekableByteChannel, and the concept of buffers.

To use:

```
Path p = Paths.get("D://logfile.txt");
try (LogLineReader reader = new LogLineReader(p)) {
  for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
    // do something with line
  }
}
```

You must ensure the LLR object is closed, hence, use try-with-resources.

Comment: Thank you, You solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Can you explain, why ``channel.position(111L)`` did you do this? Also, I think it should be ``bb.position()`` instead of ``buffer.position()`` ?

Comment: `randomAccessFile.seek(restoreOffset);` - that's what you wrote in your code. the equivalent in channel buffers is `channel.position(restoreOffset);`.